# Does authentication/authorization stop Jquery from calling a page method?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I have the following JQuery code that worked perfect in  C#/Asp.net 2.0 to call a page method in the default.aspx page. Now I am trying to call a shared page method in VB.Net and the page method is not firing, I believe because of security or it is not finding it.

The page that this shared vb method is in doesn't allow anonymous access, so I was thinking that is the problem or it is a path problem to finding the method. I am just guessing here. In my C# test app the static webmethod was in the default.aspx page with no security. Thanks for any advice or help!

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Orders.aspx/GetMailPieceGroupsByAdFundTypeId",
                data: myDataToSend,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", 
                //error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown); this;},
                success: function(data, textStatus){alert(success);mailPieceGroups = eval('(' + data + ')'); startSlideShow(mailPieceGroups); }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was the path provided was not correct which caused the .ajax call not to be able to locate the method to call it.
This is correct for my scenario:

url: "../Orders.aspx/GetMailPieceGroupsByAdFundTypeId",